# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2016

I have a datetime column `TAR_DATE` in a view with date in format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm` which I read is a [standard format for ODBC canonical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

I need to compare this `TAR_DATE` column with another date:

```
select count(1) 
from db_view 
where (case 
          when isdate(TAR_DATE) = 1 
             then convert(datetime, TAR_DATE, 121)               
      end) <= convert(datetime, '2016-08-25', 121)
```

The above query is throwing an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Whereas performing the conversions individually such as below are working fine:

```
select 
    (case
        when isdate(TAR_DATE) = 1 
           then convert(datetime, TAR_DATE, 121) 
     end) 
from 
    db_view 

select convert(datetime, '2016-08-25', 121)
```

What is causing this?

Using `try_convert()` also isn't working. Does it have something to do with the data being in a view rather than a table?

Comment: Use try_convert().   I suspect you have some bogus/unexpected data.  It won't throw an error, but it will return NULL for the strings which fail conversion.

Comment: Hi, try_convert() is till giving the same error. I applied it as suggested by Andomar below.

Answer (score 3):

The optimizer can evaluate a `case` statement in an unexpected order.  It could decide to evaluate the `then` branch first and use its result only when the `when` condition is met.  So surprisingly you can get an error for rows where you do not expect the `then` condition to be executed.

Using [`try_convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) prevents this issue, and it's easier to read as well:

```
wehre  try_convert(datetime, TAR_DATE, 121) <= '2016-08-25'
```

If the conversion fails, `try_convert` returns `null` instead of raising an error.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Using try_convert is still giving the same error.

Comment: @suneel . . . I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why. try_convert was working fine with individual conversions as specified in the question but when I use it in where clause, it is giving this error

Comment: Does it have something to do with the data being in a view instead of a table?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention **try_** convert?

Comment: @Andomar- I applied it just now

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `try_convert()`.  However, if the value is in ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD . . . format, then you don't even need to convert:

```
where tar_date < '2016-08-26'
```

The string comparison is sufficient.

Comment: @Suneel . . . If this is giving an error, you have a bug in the view.  It is not the query that is causing the problem (the query is not doing any data type conversion in the outer `select`).

Comment: Could you please suggest some way to identify the bug in the view.